# Update the state of the grandparent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'd like to update a state value of the grandparent component:

```
class GrandChild extends React.Component {
  changeNumber() {
    // this.setState(prevState => ({
    //   number: prevState.number + 1 // Add 1
    // }));

    // I want to set the state of the App Component instead of the GrandChild component
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>The number is {this.props.number}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.changeNumber}>Increase number by 1</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <GrandChild number={this.props.number}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      number: 1
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Child number={this.state.number}/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I did code this in CodePen for those who want to test the code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEeQdr

I hope there's a simple solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either you can pass a callback from the grandparent to the grandchild and the grandchild call it when needed or you can use a global state management system such as Redux or Mobx.

Comment: Sure, either use a statemanagement framework like redux or others, or pass a callback function down so your grandchild can interact through callback functions

Comment: lift the state up. Ref:  https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: check [working code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PQKXjJ?editors=0010), but better to use redux/flux for data management, it will be helpful in these kind of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class GrandChild extends React.Component {
  changeNumber=()=> {
    this.props.changeNumber();//call parent `changeNumber` method
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>The number is {this.props.number}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.changeNumber}>Increase number by 1</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <GrandChild number={this.props.number} changeNumber={this.props.changeNumber} /> //passed `changeNumber` as it is to `GrandChild`
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      number: 1
    }
  }

  changeNumber=()=>{


    this.setState((prevState)=>{
      console.log(prevState);
      return {
        number :  prevState.number + 1
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Child number={this.state.number} changeNumber = {this.changeNumber}/> //passed `changeNumber` to Child
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Working [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEeJVZ?editors=1011#anon-login)

Comment: Don't you love code only answers, how about adding some text to your answer?

Comment: @Icepickle :) will take care.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check working code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class GrandChild extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>The number is {this.props.number}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.props.incNumber}>Increase number by 1</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GrandChild number={this.props.number} incNumber={this.props.incNumber} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      number: 1
    };
  }
  incrementNumber = () => {
    this.setState({ number: this.state.number + 1 });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Child number={this.state.number} incNumber={this.incrementNumber} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Don't you love code only answers, how about adding some text to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can send method body as a prop to Child Class, as a pointer to it, and when you wil lcal this method in the Child, it will properly executed in the Parent, where was declared.

```
class GrandChild extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>The number is {this.props.passedProps.number}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => 
this.props.passedProps.increaseNumber()}>Increase number by 1</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GrandChild passedProps={this.props}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      number: 1
    }
  }

  increaseNumber = () => {
    this.setState({ number: this.state.number + 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child number={this.state.number} increaseNumber={this.increaseNumber}/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Don't you love code only answers, how about adding some text to your answer?